# Two different log formats for django and celery

Tags: python, django, logging, celery, django-celery

Is it possible to have different log formats for celery tasks and Django? 
What I want is two different log formats. In celery logs i want additional `task_id` and `processName` parameters.
Below is my Django logger settings,

```
class LoggerSettingsMixin(object):

    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'default': {
                'format': '[%(asctime)s] [rid:%(request_id)s] [crid:%(client_request_id)s] [aid:%(actor_id)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(lineno)d:%(name)s] - %(message)s'
            },
            'celery': {
                'format': '[%(asctime)s] [%(processName)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(lineno)d:%(name)s] - %(message)s'
            },
         },
        'filters': {
            'request_id': {
                '()': 'request_id.logging.RequestIdFilter'
            },
            'client_request_id': {
                '()': 'apps.commons.logging_filters.ClientRequestIdFilter'
            },
            'actor_id': {
                '()': 'apps.commons.logging_filters.ActorFilter'
            },
            'task_id': {
                '()': 'apps.commons.logging_filters.CeleryTaskIdFilter'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'INFO',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'filters': ['request_id', 'actor_id', 'client_request_id', 'task_id'],
                'formatter': 'default',
            },
            'celery': {
                'level': 'INFO',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'celery',
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'statsd': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': False,
            },
            'celery': {
                'handlers': ['celery'],
                'level': 'INFO',
                'propagate': False,
            },
            'celery.redirected': {
                'handlers': ['celery'],
                'level': 'INFO',
                'propagate': False,
            },
            '': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'INFO',
                'propagate': True,
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is my signals, where i am trying to override the celery root logger ,

```
@after_setup_logger.connnect
def setup_logger(**options):
    logger = get_logger('')
    logger.handlers = []
    logger.addFilter(ActorFilter())
    logger.addFilter(ClientRequestIdFilter())
    logger.addFilter(CeleryTaskIdFilter())
    logger.addFilter(RequestIdFilter())
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] [%(processName)s][rid:%(request_id)s [crid:%(client_request_id)s] [aid:%(actor_id)s] [taskid:%(task_id)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(lineno)d:%(name)s] - %(message)s')
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Also i have tried with setting up a logger for celery.redirected but its still not working.
in settings, `CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False`

On trying to execute task it gives the log error,

```
[2017-07-26 21:09:17,377] [MainProcess] [INFO] [402:celery.worker.job] - Task apps.apis.reports.tasks.update_pipeline_reports[a6698044-a209-4fdf-8ab6-e6a1affb5efd] succeeded in 0.158420855005s: None
[2017-07-26 21:09:19,927] [PoolWorker-4] [WARNING] [282:celery.redirected] - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2017-07-26 21:09:19,927] [PoolWorker-4] [WARNING] [282:celery.redirected] - File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 861, in emit
[2017-07-26 21:09:19,927] [PoolWorker-4] [WARNING] [282:celery.redirected] - msg = self.format(record)
[2017-07-26 21:09:19,928] [PoolWorker-4] [WARNING] [282:celery.redirected] - File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 734, in format
[2017-07-26 21:09:19,928] [PoolWorker-4] [WARNING] [282:celery.redirected] - return fmt.format(record)
[2017-07-26 21:09:19,928] [PoolWorker-4] [WARNING] [282:celery.redirected] - File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 469, in format
[2017-07-26 21:09:19,929] [PoolWorker-4] [WARNING] [282:celery.redirected] - s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
[2017-07-26 21:09:19,929] [PoolWorker-4] [WARNING] [282:celery.redirected] - KeyError: 'request_id'
[2017-07-26 21:09:19,929] [PoolWorker-4] [WARNING] [282:celery.redirected] - Logged from file tasks.py, line 32
```

Also when i am not trying to override the root logger in `after_setup_logger` signal , it picks up the default Django format and prints logs without error.